# iTunes Connect Internal Testing Page Broken

Tags: ios, testing, app-store-connect, testflight

I've been seeing this for the past 2 days. Is it just me? Does anyone know what's going on? Testflight is broken again.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of this madness, everything seems to work...